# Jenkins deploy NodeJS app on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, jenkins

Firstly, it's the first time that I'm working with Jenkins. I want Jenkins to build my NodeJS app and deploy it to Azure. I can succesfully trigger my build through bitbucket and I can succesfully set my Post-build to "Publish an Azure Web App".

So thing that I don't know exactly how to do, are the building steps. I think that I should create an artifact but I can't find a proper documentation.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar issue, I'm preparing a build by npm install than tar czf everything needed and then using the Post-build to "Publish an Azure Web App" but after running this (which is succesfull) can't see the app working on proper endpoint.
I guess that I have a lack of some steps, are you able to send me a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article that we followed for setting up Jenkins to build nodejs - 
https://codeforgeek.com/2016/04/continuous-integration-deployment-jenkins-node-js/

As you have figured out how to kick the build and deploy on Azure just read about steps to build on Jenkins.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I just needed to add npm install in the shell option. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Glad to help, Cheers :)